# On / with a low budget

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

I've got this piece of my text:

> In my humble opinion, a movie can be just as good and entertaining on a low budget with certain key elements.

Is it correct to say 'on a low budget' or it's better to use 'with' here?

Comment: "On a low budget" is fine, but the construction isn't. It isn't clear what *on a low budget* refers to. Is it the movie goer, or the production of the movie, or something else.

Comment: @PhilSweet got it, thank you!

Comment: I agree with the first comment. If the sentence were stopped after *budget*, everything would be fine. The additional wording make it unclear what's being expressed or compared.